# How to solve "NameError: name 'plotly_version' is not defined" when using simple_plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, jupyter

I'm trying to draw a map for my master thesis code. By now I'm just trying an example from https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/e2nIEE/pandapower/blob/develop/tutorials/plotly_maps.ipynb so I imagined everything should work properly. However, when trying to use the function "simple_plotly" a NameError appears. How can I manage to make it work?

*This is the line where I get the error:*

```
from pandapower.plotting.plotly import simple_plotly
from pandapower.networks import mv_oberrhein
net = mv_oberrhein()
simple_plotly(net, on_map=True, projection='epsg:31467')
```

Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-9381f16ca1ad> in <module>()
      9 
     10 net = mv_oberrhein()
---> 11 simple_plotly(net, on_map=True, projection='epsg:31467')

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandapower/plotting/plotly/simple_plotly.py in simple_plotly(net, respect_switches, use_line_geodata, on_map, projection, map_style, figsize, aspectratio, line_width, bus_size, ext_grid_size, bus_color, line_color, trafo_color, ext_grid_color)
    116         **ext_grid_color** (String, 'yellow') - External Grid Color. Init is yellow
    117     """
--> 118     version_check()
    119     # create geocoord if none are available
    120     if 'line_geodata' not in net:

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandapower/plotting/plotly/traces.py in version_check()
     33 
     34 def version_check():
---> 35     if version.parse(plotly_version) < version.parse("3.1.1"):
     36         raise UserWarning("Your plotly version {} is no longer supported.\r\n"
     37                           "Please upgrade your python-plotly installation, "

NameError: name 'plotly_version' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because plotly is not installed, install ploty with pip and it will work.

```
Pip install plotly
```